# Tracking And Aggregating Individual User Paths Using Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-application-insights

I am relatively new to using Application Insights, and I am working for a small sized tech start up.

Our company in interested in using Applications Insights to track the paths of individual users using our web application. I have been reading a lot of Microsoft documentation, but I am having trouble on finding that one page or one magical stack overflow answer that clarifies the process of doing this.

I've been working primarily in a Linux environment and the jump to developing in a Microsoft Windows environment, and adapting to Microsoft development tools has been a bit of a jump! Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Is this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-users useful?

Answer (score 2):

User Flows is a great way to see an aggregate view of the behavior of your users. If you would like to view how a specific individual user interacts with your web application, I would suggest using the User Timeline feature, which can be found under Related Insights in Search, or under Meet Your Users in the Users blade.

Comment: if you want to filter to just one user, if you know their id you can set that as a filter in the 'edit' panel of the flows view.